# JavaScript - load second image frames on the end of the first image cycle

Tags: javascript

I have an image called `frames.png`. Actually it is not an image frame, it's a large height image containing sections called "frames". Example: http://s21.postimg.org/i3fortt5z/frames.png

On DOM is ready, the frame (*or if you like it better section*) #1 is shown, then 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ... until frame #11. So basically the absolute top position of the large height image is changed on a regular time interval.

Until this phase everything is working. You can see a live working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/henrichro/PCa5Q/2/

Concretely with this approach you can use your creativity and build nice "animations" in HTML & JS.

**What I need to do:**

When the animation arrives to the last frame/section of the first image, I'd would like to load the second image. When hitting the last frame/section of the second image, if no more images are loaded inline the HTML code, to begin the animation from first frame/section of the very first image.

I don't know how to proceed. If it is okay loading the images inline, if there is another cross-browser and cross-device (iPad, iPhone, etc.) possibility. Or maybe I should use an array of images in JavaScript? What I do know, the `step` variable from the `startAnimation` function is returning the number of frames/section of the image. The full height of the object is taken and divided on the offset height declared in CSS (`.animation-frame`). When we hit the last frame/section, there should happen a load into the cycle, but I don't know how to do this.

**Why I am loading more than one image, instead of using one large height image?**

Because Firefox is having a problem with very large images: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/973667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to just have all you images inline so they are loaded as fast as possible. A few problems with this:

1. You say you're using the `DOM ready` event which is fine, but it could be the case that the first image has not been fully downloaded when you begin. The chances of this happening are bigger when you start downloading multiple images in parallel, especially on a mobile device. EDIT: I see that you do not use the `DOM ready`, but the `onload` event. This will fix the problem, but the animation won't start until all of the images are loaded.
2. You are downloading all the images all of the time, even if the user does not look at them all. This is a waste of bandwidth. It is only a real issue if you are loading many images though.

So alternatively you could use the JavaScript `Image` object to manually load the images at the time you want to.

The trick would be to start loading the next (couple of) images at the right time. Creating some sort of buffer

I would just go with the first approach though. Just load them all and start with the next image as son as you reached the end of the first one.

Here's an example of how to do this. It works and shows how to iterate over a set of images:  http://jsfiddle.net/PCa5Q/8/

Her's the code:

```
var direction = -1;

function animateImg( img, step, moveHeight, callback) {

    if (step * moveHeight > img.height)  {
       callback();
    } else {
        img.style.top = (step * moveHeight * direction) + "px";
        setTimeout(function() {
            animateImg(img, step + 1, moveHeight, callback);
        }, 220); 
    }
}
function startAnimation(animateFrame, imgs, imgCounter) {
     // If we reached the last image we start over again.
    if (imgCounter >= imgs.length) imgCounter = 0;

    var currentImg = document.getElementById(imgs[imgCounter]);
    var moveHeight = parseInt( animateFrame.offsetHeight );

    // Show the current image (by default they are all invisible: see CSS)
    currentImg.style.display = 'block';

    animateImg(currentImg, 0, moveHeight, function() {
        // Hide the current image
        currentImg.style.display = 'none';

        // start with the next image
        startAnimation(animateFrame, imgs, imgCounter + 1);
    }); 
}
window.onload = function() {
    var imgs = ['animationImageOne', 'animationImageTwo'];
    var animateFrame = document.getElementById( 'animationFrame' );
    startAnimation(animateFrame, imgs, 0);
}
```

and some additional CSS:

```
img {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. It took some time until I've figured out your direction but now I understand also the code you've added. This is very nice! :) With current scenario I imagine plenty ways to upgrade the code for different device scenarios which is awesome. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

You can add callback to startAnimation function and call it after last iteration:

```
if (currentStep === step) {
    clearInterval(animationInterval);
    if (callback) callback();
}
```

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PCa5Q/3/